# What the technical difference between Serviceability, Manageability and Maintainability of a system?

Tags: computer-architecture, maintenance, computing-environment

Aren't Serviceability and Maintainability almost serve the same purpose in term of IT architecture so how to they exactly differ?

Comment: somthing tells me that these are loaded definitions that are consistent only within a frame of reference, like a curriculum, so our answers will not be nearly so specific to your needs as your text book's.  the words do have canonical meaning that, when grouped together, allow us to draw inferences as to what the author meant, but it sounds like someone is asking you a specific question that they expect you to already know the answer to, because they already told you.

Answer (score 2):

#### Maintainability vs. Serviceability

**Serviceability** (or supportability), refers to the ease of recovering from (or preventing) failures; how effectively/efficiently the system can be kept running.  It focuses on things like diagnostic tools, accessibility of hardware components and availability of replacement components.

Source to get you started: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serviceability_%28computer%29

**Maintainability** is a broader term that can include serviceability.  It refers to the bigger picture of keeping users' needs met.  It includes the ease with which the system can:

- be fixed when it fails
- be prevented from failing
- be modified to improve performance
- have it's useful life extended
- be adapted to meet new requirements or a changing environment

Source to get you started: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintainability

Or, as defined in IEEE Standard Computer Dictionary: A Compilation of IEEE Standard Computer Glossaries. New York, NY: Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers, 1990:

> The ease with which a software system or component can be modified to correct faults, improve performance, or other attributes, or adapt to a changed environment.

#### Manageability

**Manageability** refers to the ease with which the system can be monitored and maintained to keep it performing, secure, and running smoothly.  Its focus is more directly on the system admninistrator than the users, providing the tools and controls to facilitate that job.

Answer (score 1):

Maintainability means you keep a piece of equipment, machine, or system functional from a hardware perspective and can repair it if it malfunctions. Example: a physical server.

Serviceability means you make sure the services provided by the respective device are fully functional, so it practically is the ability to technically support (yourself or via other personnel) the installation, configuration, and monitoring of devices/products, identification of exceptions or errors/faults. Example: the applications of the server.

Manageability is how well you can control that device. Example: how fast and efficient can you access the server.